# problems with tracking user in a chat with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, backend

I'm trying to build a real-time chat with socket.io. However, I'm having some problems with the user. Once set with the "userSet" event, the "user" variable becomes undefined outside the event. Could you help me?

Server:

```js
  const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer);

app.use(express.static("./www"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

const users = [];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/www/index.html");
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Utente connesso");
  console.log(users.toString());
  socket.on("setUsername", (data) => {
    if (users.indexOf(data) > -1) {
      socket.emit("checkUser", "Il nome " + data + " è già stato preso. Riprova con un altro.");
    } else users.push(data);
    console.log("Benvenuto " + data);
    socket.emit("userSet", data);
  });

  socket.on("messaggio", (data) => {
    console.log("mes: " + data);
    io.emit("mostraMessaggio", data);
  });
});

httpServer.listen(3000);
```

Client:

```js
      const socket = io();
var par;

function setUsername() {
  socket.emit("setUsername", document.getElementById("username").value);
}

let user;

socket.on("userSet", (data) => {
  user = data;
  alert("set " + user + " " + data);
});

socket.on("checkUser", (data) => {
  alert(data);
  alert("c" + user);
});

function inviaMessaggio() {
  const msg = document.getElementById("testo").value;
  alert("i " + user);
  if (msg) {
    socket.emit("messaggio", msg);
  }
}

socket.on("mostraMessaggio", (data) => {
  if (user) {
    par = document.createElement("p");
    par.id = "messaggio";
    par.innerHTML = user + ": " + data;
    document.getElementById("chat").appendChild(par);
  }
});
```

I've already tried passing the username as a json, for example with `{msg: msg, user:user}`. But the problem is that right outside the `userSet` event the user variable is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The scoping issue with the `user` variable.
To resolve this issue, you need to declare the `user` variable in a broader scope, so it can be accessed throughout the module. You can do this by declaring it outside of the event handler.

Here's an updated version of your client-side code:

```js
const socket = io();
var par;
let user; // Declare user variable outside of the setUsername function

function setUsername() {
  const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  socket.emit("setUsername", username);
}

socket.on("userSet", (data) => {
  user = data;
  alert("set " + user + " " + data);
});

socket.on("checkUser", (data) => {
  alert(data);
  alert("c" + user);
});

function inviaMessaggio() {
  const msg = document.getElementById("testo").value;
  alert("i " + user);
  if (msg) {
    socket.emit("messaggio", msg);
  }
}

socket.on("mostraMessaggio", (data) => {
  if (user) {
    par = document.createElement("p");
    par.id = "messaggio";
    par.innerHTML = user + ": " + data;
    document.getElementById("chat").appendChild(par);
  }
});
```